# Basic Error Propagation: Do we use the formula of the original equation to calculate uncertainty?

Tags: error-propagation

This is a very basic question. I have been asked to find the uncertainty for $F_{c,th}=\frac{4\pi^2mr}{T^2}$. What would be the formula for $\delta F_{c,th}$ given that $m$, $r$ and $T$ are measured values.

What I tried: I only calculated uncertainty based on the operations between the measured variables. After using uncertainty rules, I got: $$F_{c,th}= \frac{\delta r}{|r|}+\frac{\delta m}{|m|}+2\frac{\delta T}{|T|}$$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The left side should be $\frac {\delta F_{c,th}}{F_{c,th}}$  You took the log and then the differential on the right and should do the same on the left.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't write that it was the relative uncertainty for the $F_{c,th}$. Not sure what you mean by the log and the differential.

Comment: That is how you get your equation for the uncertainty.  If you take the log of the right side you get terms like $\log m - 2 \log r$.  Then when you take the differential you get $\frac {\delta m}m + 2\frac {\delta r}r$